# Multi Column Search in a ListView

Tags: c#, listview

Ok...  so I have got a working procedure to search a ListView. This procedure
works successfully however, it only searches 1 of 5 columns. My desire is to 
get the procedure to search the first 2 columns which are forename and surname. I found a line of code which is suppose to do it but after compilation, it produces an error. Below is an excerpt of my code. and the line I am trying to use.

Thanks in advance for all the help and advice

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        string s = "    Search Via Forename";
        int result = 0;
        int count = 0;
        result = string.Compare(textBox1.Text, s);

        if ((result == 0) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please input forename...");
            return;
        }

       foreach(ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems)
       {
            if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                count++;                        
                statusBar1.Panels[2].Text = "Found: " + count.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                listView1.Items.Remove(item); 
            }
        }

        button1.Text = "Clear";
        textBox1.Visible = false;
        button3.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = false;
  }
```

Comment: *"but after compilation, it produces an error"* - What error? Which code line?

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'item' does not exist in the current context

Comment: In which code line in the code above?

Comment: The errors occurs with the variable item where the asterisk are in the code. I tried to make the errors outstanding but unable to do so

Comment: I provided an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are referencing an undeclared variables called `item` that was never declared or instanciated.

When looping through the list items, you need to use:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
```

This will iterate the `ListView`'s `Items` with a variable called `item` that will hold the current item on each iteration.

Try this code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string s = "    Search Via Forename";
     int result = 0;
     int count = 0;
     result = string.Compare(textBox1.Text, s);

     if ((result == 0) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)))
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Please input forename...");
         return;
     }

     foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
     {
         if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
         {
             count++;                        
             statusBar1.Panels[2].Text = "Found: " + count.ToString();
         }
         else
         {
             listView1.Items.Remove(item); 
         }
     }

     button1.Text = "Clear";
     textBox1.Visible = button3.Visible = button2.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: the code you supplied, does the same thing that my code does. It only searches the first column. I want to search the first and second colums